# adding color to the active radio button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two radio buttons and I want to add a background color to the active radio button.
I tried to add it via a condition but it seems to be not working. What am i doing wrong here?
I'm getting `Cannot read property 'gender' of undefined` error

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  const [gender, setGender] = React.useState();
  return (
    <div className="App">
          <Radio
            label="male"
            value="male"
            checked={gender}
            setter={setGender}
            style={{backgroundColor: this.state.gender == 'male' ? 'red': 'white'}}
          />
          <Radio
            label="female"
            value="female"
            checked={gender}
            setter={setGender}
            style={{backgroundColor: this.state.gender == 'female' ? 'red': 'white'}}
          />
    </div>
  );
}
const Radio = ({ label, value, checked, setter }) => {
  return (
    <div className="radio">
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          checked={checked === value}
          onChange={() => setter(value)}
        />
        <span>{label}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

When using react hooks, you do not need to use `this.state.gender...`

Try this:

```
<div className="App">
          <Radio
            label="male"
            value="male"
            checked={gender}
            setter={setGender}
            style={{backgroundColor: gender === 'male' ? 'red': 'white'}}
          />
          <Radio
            label="female"
            value="female"
            checked={gender}
            setter={setGender}
            style={{backgroundColor: gender === 'female' ? 'red': 'white'}}
          />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Few changes required

1-Always provide initial value

```
  const [gender, setGender] = React.useState('');
```

2- Since you are using hooks, don't need to use `this.state`

```
style={{backgroundColor: gender === 'male' ? 'red': 'white'}}
```

If you are trying to change background color on selection of radio button, Replace Radio component with below.

```
const Radio = ({ label, value, checked, setter, style }) => {
  return (
    <div className="radio" style={style}>
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          checked={checked === value}
          onChange={() => setter(value)}
        />
        <span>{label}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-kowalevski-1bdh3)

Comment: I dont see the background color. it's still white

Comment: @deadbeforesunlight are you trying to change background color on selection of radio button?